# finding a non existing value in one table that corresponds to a pairing in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that i am working with. The first table is called temp6 with columns labeled as bsite, bsector, msite, msector, esite, esector, bpn, epn. The second table is called homdatapairs with columns labeled as fromcell, fromsector, tocell, tosector, hocount, percentage.

The goal is to produce a table that consists of bsite, bsector, msite, msector, hocount and percentage. The problem im running into is that the pairing of bsite, bsector, msite, msector does not exist in the homdatapairs table. So logically it should return the bsite, bsector, msite, msector, hocount and percentage leaving NULL values in hocount and percentage but it is not returning anything at all (no errors are occuring either).

Here is my query:

```
SELECT t6.bsite
     , t6.bsector
     , t6.msite
     , t6.msector
     , IFNULL(p.hocount, 0)
     , IFNULL(p.percentage, 0)
  FROM homdatapairs p
     , temp6 t6
 WHERE t6.bsite = p.fromcell 
   AND t6.bsector = p.fromsector 
   AND t6.msite = p.tocell 
   AND t6.msector = p.tosector;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Here is the query that works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t6.bsite, t6.bsector, t6.msite, t6.msector, IF(t6.msite = p.tocell AND t6.msector = p.tosector, IFNULL(p.hocount,0), 0), IF(t6.msite = p.tocell AND t6.msector = p.tosector, IFNULL(p.percentage, 0), 0)
FROM homdatapairs p, temp6 t6
WHERE t6.bsite = p.fromcell AND t6.bsector = p.fromsector;
```